# Scaling problem when projected map is overlaid on basemap in QGIS

Tags: gdalwarp, gdal-translate, mapping, offset

### The problem

My georeferenced and projected Matplotlib map overlays with an offset on a basemap projected in QGIS with the same coordinate reference system.

### What I did:

I created a map in Matplotlib and saved it in the usual way (as a tif) using savefig. This tif file has no georeferencing. I then used a system call from my Python script to GDAL translate to add georeferencing. The resulting GeoTIFF has georeferencing. Finally I used GDAL warp to project the data.

I started a clean project in QGIS, and loaded the Google satellite basemap. I then added my projected Matplotlib map as a raster layer. The screenshot of the overlay (linked below) shows that there is an offset between the basemap and the map overlay. This seems to be a scaling problem, but I'd like to be able to fix the problem. Any help would be great.

Here's a link to the files mentioned: [tiff files and screenshot](http://u.pc.cd/WEA)

Here's some of the relevant Python code:

---

### Save the Matplotlib map

---

```
plt.savefig(   "/mnt/data/dynamic_data/projects/projects2022/recreational_fishing_GHRSST/figures/plot_SST_fronts_"+region+".tif",
        format="tif",
        bbox_inches='tight', 
        dpi=300
    )
```

---

### Get the corner coordinates from the data

---

```
ds_raster = rasterio.open("/mnt/data/dynamic_data/projects/projects2022/recreational_fishing_GHRSST/data/"+region+"_sst.tif")
bounds = ds_raster.bounds
left= bounds.left
bottom = bounds.bottom
right = bounds.right
top = bounds.top
# construct ullr string to use in gdal_translate
ullr = [left, bottom, right, top]
ullr_string = ' '.join(str(e) for e in ullr)
```

---

### Write the georeferencing to the Matplotlib map using GDAL translate

---

```
os.system("gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_ullr "+ullr_string+" -a_srs EPSG:4326 /mnt/data/dynamic_data/projects/projects2022/recreational_fishing_GHRSST/figures/plot_SST_fronts_"+region+".tif /mnt/data/dynamic_data/projects/projects2022/recreational_fishing_GHRSST/figures/plot_SST_fronts_"+region+"_trans.tif -co TILED=YES")
```

---

### Project the georeferenced map using GDAL warp

---

```
os.system("gdalwarp -t_srs '+proj=merc +datum=WGS84' /mnt/data/dynamic_data/projects/projects2022/recreational_fishing_GHRSST/figures/plot_SST_fronts_"+region+"_trans.tif /mnt/data/dynamic_data/projects/projects2022/recreational_fishing_GHRSST/figures/plot_SST_fronts_"+region+"_proj.tif")
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be that QGIS is picking up on the bounding box rather than the axes of the map. If I remove the map colorbar, axis labels, and title, the overlay aligns perfectly.[image]